# Repair topology before pgrouting / No results of pgrouting

Tags: pgrouting, osm2po, dijkstra

My goal is to calculate lots of distances along the streets. I followed http://workshop.pgrouting.org/ tutorial except that I used osm2po instead of osm2pgrouting to import osm file. The only problem I'm facing now are gaps in results - Dijkstra algorithm seems to fail in finding the route between two nodes of the network in 10% of cases. It simply returns nothing, empty table. I suppose the problem is with the map, that it's not "routable enough" (I can't imagine any other reason). Did anyone have the same situation? Do you know how to fix it? [image]

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31174/osm2po-vs-osm2pgrouting-workshop-pgrouting

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how it might help me. If I use osm2pgrouting I'd get the results?

Answer (score 1):

With osm2po (and some basic Java skills) this is possible. Call DefaultRouter with a random vertex sourceId and set the targetId to 0. This lets the Dijkstra expand the complete graph. Finally call getVisited() to collect all visited vertices. Vertices which are not visited belong to isolated edges. If you've randomly hit an isolated vertex you'll receive a rather small set of visited nodes. If so, start over with next random.